# Remainder of nested exponents problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, integers, totient-function

**The problem:** Find $3^{31^{2023}} \mod 23$

**My attempt:**

From Fermat's little theorem, we have $$31^{22}\equiv 1 \Rightarrow (31^{22})^{92} \equiv 1  \Rightarrow 31^{2024} \equiv 1 \mod 23$$ Motivated by this we first determine $31^{2023} \mod 23$.  We let $a \equiv 31^{2023} \mod 23$. It follows that:

\begin{align*}
    a &\equiv 31^{2023} \\
    31 \cdot a &\equiv 31^{2024}  \\
    8 \cdot a &\equiv 1 \\
    24 \cdot a  &\equiv 3  \\
    a & \equiv 3 
\end{align*}

Then we have:

$$3^{31^{2023}} \equiv 3^3  \equiv 4 \mod 23$$

So we have $3^{31^{2023}} \mod 23 \equiv 4$

**Error:**
Although I got the right answer, I was told that although $31^{2023} \equiv 3 \mod 23$ is correct, it does not follow that $3^{31^{2023}} \equiv 3^3 \mod 23$ and by Euler's Theorem, I have to calculate $31^{2023} \mod 22$. I'm just not sure how and in what situation I need to apply this to, although I did find that $31^{2023} \equiv 3 \mod 22$.

Can someone help explain Euler's theorem again and how to apply it in general for nested exponents?

*P.S. I'm not really sure what tags to use for this so feel free to change it if my tags aren't right.*